# вопросы по Service . Service без активити, неявный вызов service

Tags: java, android, android-service

http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/159-urok-94-service-podrobno-pro-onstartcommand.html

в этом вот уроке, написанном в 2012 году, автор создает сервис а отдельном проекте. Создает еще один проект с активити. Передает интент с Action и настраивает интент фильтр service . И сперва он устанавливает в эмулятор сервис. он установился , но процесс его не запускается. Ставит проект с активити, жмет кнопку , передает интент и сервис запускается, появился процесс сервиса.      У меня же сейчас это не срабатывает, когда я устанавливаю сервис вижу в логе

```
I/ActivityManager: Force stopping startandroid.servicebindserver appid=10064 user=0: from pid 3592
```

Что значит это строка? Я понимаю, что сразу же убивается этот сервис, но ведь я и не просил его запускать. 
  Ну и естественно когда я запускаю приложение и пытаюсь отправить интент для запуска сервиса получаю ошибку. 
в логе написано , что интент должен быть ЯВным. но я хочу неявный, через Action.
 Если мой вопрос не связан с изменениями в андроид и ошибка может быть где то у меня в коде, то я приложу код с логом , но я думаю что , что то изменилось в андроид.

Comment: все статьи старше 2016 года смело игнорируйте

Comment: Сомневаюсь в верности вашего комментария

Comment: Я понял, что на андроид выше 4 нельзя передать в startService()  неявный интент.  Значит больше никак нельзя использовать action для вызова сервиса?

Comment: так могут делать только системные приложения, или нужны как минимум рут права. старт сервиса без активности невозможен.

Comment: с рутом используя терминал можно поместить jar и java.class в сервис независимо не от чего, аналогично linux системам. А в том примере ничего необычного нету.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После некоторого обновления  использовать action для вызова сервиса  нельзя. Видать в целях безопасности закрыли такую возможность. Теперь надо конкретно знать, что такой то сервис установлен и его package такой то.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще насколько я понимаю в целях безопасности сервис может быть запущен только с активити. Правда я могу ошибаться. Если Вам нужен просто сервис без активити, то это делается так

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Service.class, this);
startService(intent);

this.finish();
```

Прописывается это все в MainActivity и оно закрывается сразу после запуска. 
Но мне почему-то кажется, что я неправильно Вас понял)

Comment: Ну так сервис то нужен без активити, какой смысл в  mainActivity   что-то прописывать

Comment: Андрей Беспалов, вот мне нужно не то как вы понимаете)  В уроках явно написано, что создается проект без единого активити , в проекте есть одно сервис.  И он устанавливается в телефон.  В уроке так же написано, что этот сервис сам не запустится после установки как сделало бы приложение с активити.  Это как раз в целях безопасности.  А потом через стороннее приложение через неявный вызов,  я могу включить этот сервис. Но не получается.  В логе написано,  используйте явный вызов.  А мне нужен узнать про неявный.  Катит ли такое или с каких пор не катит

Comment: McDaggen, должно быть два проекта.  В одном сервис без активити и настроенный интент фильтр. А во втором в активити делается неявный вызов используя action прописанный в проекте сервиса